# Saving a modified GPT partition map to a file in GParted or similar tools

Tags: gparted, gpt

I can use `sgdisk -b /dev/sdx` to save the GPT partition map of a disk to a file. I want to generate such a file for a GPT with one partition of a certain size. The only way I can see to do this is to actually format a disk in a tool like GParted then use `gdisk` to save the GPT.

Is there a way, preferably in GParted, to set up a GPT table with my desired partitions then save it to a file instead of writing it to disk?

Other non-desireable options:

- Manually edit a dump from `sgdisk`. Too hard to get things right.
- Create a VirtualBox disk of the desired size, format it, then export with `sgdisk`. Would take forever for the 440GiB disk I want. **Edit: Actually, this is fast if I use a dynamically allocated virtual disk, but it's a clunky solution.**

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question is related to the partition table and the partitions and not the data. If this is correct then your answer is already in the man pages for `parted` and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200582/scripteable-gpt-partitions-using-parted#200598).

In essence create a script of the `parted` commands necessary to create your gpt scheme and then

```
parted --script /dev/sdx [script commands]
```

This can be put into a shell script and executed as you need, perhaps passing the device as an argument to the script.

**Edit after comment:** According to the `man sgdisk` page, to get the sgdisk output for a 'phantom' disk, use the '-P' option which performs the task(s) in memory but does not commit changes to disk.

I just tried this with a usb and it appears to work

```
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 31653888 sectors, 15.1 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2016C547-548B-482E-8810-A5E7A1466CED
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 31653854
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4029 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048        31651839   15.1 GiB    0700  IDEA    #old name


sudo sgdisk -P -c 1:random -p /dev/sdb                           #change the name

Setting name!
partNum is 0
REALLY setting name!
Disk /dev/sdb: 31653888 sectors, 15.1 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2016C547-548B-482E-8810-A5E7A1466CED
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 31653854
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4029 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048        31651839   15.1 GiB    0700  random   #name changed
```

re-executing

```
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdb


Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048        31651839   15.1 GiB    0700  IDEA    #change not written
```

The change is also reflected in the output from

```
sudo sgdisk -P -c 1:random --backup=phantomDisk /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Doesn't this still apply the changes to the `/dev/sdx` disk, erasing all data? I was looking to output the resulting GPT table rather than writing it to disk.